# Prevent page creation automatically from wander.php WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, http-status-code-404, zombie-process

Our site is built with WordPress CMS
We bought the template from Forest Theme
It generates a series of 404 links automatically every day

........./wander.php?items/bep9543wjketidm3031.html

Can you advise how to fix this problem so that zombie pages are not created
Thankful.

No matter what I looked for in the server, I could not find the name of that file

Comment: Have you ran a malware check? Generating links like this is quite unusual and can suggest you may have a malware infection.